# How to use Hamcrest's AssertThat for String[]

Tags: java, maven, hamcrest, assertthat

So I've been looking around and trying to find a solution to this problem but I'm coming up with either compiler errors or weird expectations or both. 
So here we go:

```
this.mockPersonNode.setProperty("fname",new String[] {"John"});
...unrelated code...
//validate traits
final String[] fname = (String[]) groovy.getProperty("firstName");
//This is where my problems lie
assertThat(fname, hasProperty("John"));
```

So this code compile fine but when I go to build it in Maven the test fails because:`Expected: hasProperty("John"), got:[John]`

So I did some looking and checked out the other questions people got answered here but I get compile errors, I am clearly doing the assertThat wrong but how should the assertThat be set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `hasItemInArray` matcher:

```
assertThat(fname, hasItemInArray("John"));
```

The `hasProperty` matcher matches Java Bean properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assert that array `fname` contains the item `John` and nothing else you can use the  [IsArrayContainingInOrder](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/collection/IsArrayContainingInOrder.html) matcher (`Matchers.arrayContaining`):

```
assertThat(fname, arrayContaining("John"));
```

If you only care that at least one item in `fname` is `John` use the [IsArrayContaining](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/collection/IsArrayContaining.html) matcher (`Matchers.hasItemInArray`) as suggested by @hzpz.